# C++ Reversely sort characters in a string

Tags: c++, string, sorting, stl

There are tons of codes that sort an array of strings lexicographically but I can't find one that does sorting characters in ONE string reverse lexicographically. So far I discovered that using `std::sort()` in `<algorithm>` might be the closest candidate.

This is what I tried:

```
template <typename T>
class ReverseComparator{
     bool operator()(T l, T r){return !(l < r);}
};
//.....later
std::sort(str.begin(), str.end(), comparator);
```

Here's the question: how can I initialize my comparator so that it can compare the characters in the string? I tried `ReverseComparator<char> comparator` but compiler throws a ton of error msg.  [gcc-4.5.1 showed these errors](http://ideone.com/ulB623_):

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/algorithm:63:0,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
prog.cpp: In function 'void std::__insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]':
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:2192:4:   instantiated from 'void std::__final_insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:5252:4:   instantiated from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
prog.cpp:12:49:   instantiated from here
prog.cpp:6:11: error: 'bool ReverseComparator<T>::operator()(T, T) [with T = char]' is private
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:2125:4: error: within this context
prog.cpp: In function 'void std::__heap_select(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]':
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:5100:7:   instantiated from 'void std::partial_sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:2297:8:   instantiated from 'void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Size = int, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:5250:4:   instantiated from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
prog.cpp:12:49:   instantiated from here
prog.cpp:6:11: error: 'bool ReverseComparator<T>::operator()(T, T) [with T = char]' is private
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:1914:2: error: within this context
prog.cpp: In function 'void std::__move_median_first(_Iterator, _Iterator, _Iterator, _Compare) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]':
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:2260:7:   instantiated from '_RandomAccessIterator std::__unguarded_partition_pivot(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:2302:62:   instantiated from 'void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Size = int, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:5250:4:   instantiated from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
prog.cpp:12:49:   instantiated from here
prog.cpp:6:11: error: 'bool ReverseComparator<T>::operator()(T, T) [with T = char]' is private
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:108:7: error: within this context
prog.cpp:6:11: error: 'bool ReverseComparator<T>::operator()(T, T) [with T = char]' is private
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:110:4: error: within this context
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:2260:7:   instantiated from '_RandomAccessIterator std::__unguarded_partition_pivot(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:2302:62:   instantiated from 'void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Size = int, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:5250:4:   instantiated from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
prog.cpp:12:49:   instantiated from here
prog.cpp:6:11: error: 'bool ReverseComparator<T>::operator()(T, T) [with T = char]' is private
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:112:9: error: within this context
prog.cpp:6:11: error: 'bool ReverseComparator<T>::operator()(T, T) [with T = char]' is private
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:115:12: error: within this context
prog.cpp:6:11: error: 'bool ReverseComparator<T>::operator()(T, T) [with T = char]' is private
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:117:12: error: within this context
prog.cpp: In function '_RandomAccessIterator std::__unguarded_partition(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, const _Tp&, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Tp = char, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]':
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:2261:78:   instantiated from '_RandomAccessIterator std::__unguarded_partition_pivot(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:2302:62:   instantiated from 'void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Size = int, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:5250:4:   instantiated from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
prog.cpp:12:49:   instantiated from here
prog.cpp:6:11: error: 'bool ReverseComparator<T>::operator()(T, T) [with T = char]' is private
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:2229:4: error: within this context
prog.cpp:6:11: error: 'bool ReverseComparator<T>::operator()(T, T) [with T = char]' is private
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:2232:4: error: within this context
prog.cpp: In function 'void std::__unguarded_linear_insert(_RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]':
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:2133:6:   instantiated from 'void std::__insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:2192:4:   instantiated from 'void std::__final_insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:5252:4:   instantiated from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
prog.cpp:12:49:   instantiated from here
prog.cpp:6:11: error: 'bool ReverseComparator<T>::operator()(T, T) [with T = char]' is private
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:2083:7: error: within this context
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:62:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/algorithm:63,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
prog.cpp: In function 'void std::__adjust_heap(_RandomAccessIterator, _Distance, _Distance, _Tp, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Distance = int, _Tp = char, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]':
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_heap.h:434:4:   instantiated from 'void std::make_heap(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:1912:7:   instantiated from 'void std::__heap_select(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:5100:7:   instantiated from 'void std::partial_sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:2297:8:   instantiated from 'void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Size = int, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:5250:4:   instantiated from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
prog.cpp:12:49:   instantiated from here
prog.cpp:6:11: error: 'bool ReverseComparator<T>::operator()(T, T) [with T = char]' is private
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_heap.h:303:4: error: within this context
prog.cpp: In function 'void std::__push_heap(_RandomAccessIterator, _Distance, _Distance, _Tp, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Distance = int, _Tp = char, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]':
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_heap.h:316:7:   instantiated from 'void std::__adjust_heap(_RandomAccessIterator, _Distance, _Distance, _Tp, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Distance = int, _Tp = char, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_heap.h:434:4:   instantiated from 'void std::make_heap(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:1912:7:   instantiated from 'void std::__heap_select(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:5100:7:   instantiated from 'void std::partial_sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:2297:8:   instantiated from 'void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Size = int, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:5250:4:   instantiated from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
prog.cpp:12:49:   instantiated from here
prog.cpp:6:11: error: 'bool ReverseComparator<T>::operator()(T, T) [with T = char]' is private
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_heap.h:180:7: error: within this context
```

Comment: close to what I'd do.  `std::sort(str.begin(), str.end(), std::greater<char>());`

Comment: What error messages do you get?  At first glance it looks fine.

Comment: Note that `!(l < r)` is different from `l > r`. Two elements should compare to `false` if they are equal. Your comparator returns `true` in this case. Try @MooingDuck's solution, which really should be an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While solving the compiler error simply requires the `operator()` to be public as according to most other answers to this question, you should note that your comparator isn't a valid *strict* comparator. A strict comparator has to return `false` for elements which are treated as being equal. You should also use const references instead of values for the parameter types of your comparator.

I want to present you multiple options to solve your problem (not the compiler-error but the original problem, sorting a string in reversed lexical order). All of them return `false` for two equal elements.

The **first option** is your solution but I fixed the strictness:

```
template <typename T>
class ReverseComparator{
public:
     bool operator()(const T& l, const T& r){return (r < l);}
};

std::sort(str.begin(), str.end(), ReverseComparator());
```

The **second option** uses C++11's *lambda function*, but is essentially the same:

```
std::sort(str.begin(), str.end(), [](const T& l, const T& r){return (r < l);});
```

As a **third option**, as first proposed by Mooning Duck, you could simply use the std functor for `operator>` on your type `char`:

```
std::sort(str.begin(), str.end(), std::greater<char>());
```

The **fourth option** (the simplest one) would be to use the default comparator on the *reversed* string, as first proposed by Peter Wood (note the `r`!):

```
std::sort(str.rbegin(), str.rend());
```

Answer (score 6):

Usually, only the first error is relevant, so we have this:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/algorithm:63:0,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
prog.cpp: In function 'void std::__insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]':
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:2192:4:   instantiated from 'void std::__final_insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_algo.h:5252:4:   instantiated from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Compare = ReverseComparator<char>]'
prog.cpp:12:49:   instantiated from here
prog.cpp:6:11: error: 'bool ReverseComparator<T>::operator()(T, T) [with T = char]' is private
```

Most of that is simply context, so here's the key part:

```
'bool ReverseComparator<T>::operator()(T, T) [with T = char]' is private
```

Well that's easy to fix:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class ReverseComparator{
    public: //forgot this
     bool operator()(T l, T r){return !(l < r);}
};

int main() {
    std::string str = "HELLO";
    ReverseComparator<char> comparator;
    std::sort(str.begin(), str.end(), comparator);
}
```

[This compiles fine](http://ideone.com/KWtasS), however, sorts are based on what's called a "strict weak ordering", and `!(l < r)` is *not* a strict weak ordering.  Namely, `comparitor(a,a)` should return `false`, but yours returns `true`.  Luckily, the idea of sorting this way is already in the standard library under the name `std::greater`.  (`std::sort` without a comparitor uses `std::less` by default)

Comment: you should add the `std::greater` version from you comment, which is probably the best solution for the actual problem (reversed sorting).

Comment: Your solution still lacks the problem that `comparator(x, x) == true` instead of `false`. Please add this to your answer, like in your comment on the question.

Comment: ... in particular, `!(l < r)` doesn't define a strict weak order: `comparator(x, x)` would yield `true` (`x` is less than `x`) but it is required to yield `false`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl and others, thanks for the comments.  I'm sick and on vacation, so I didn't quite get all the information in there the first time.

Comment: To sort in reverse, use `rbegin`, `rend`.

Comment: @PeterWood Nice hint. I put these three options in my question together. All respect the *strictness*.

Answer (score 2):

Using `std::sort()` is clearly the right approach. The default comparator is `std::less<value_type>` where `value_type` is `decltype(*it)` for the type of the iterators passed. To change the default you'd just pass a different comparator, e.g. `std::greater<char>`.

To use your `ReverseComparator` as it is defined you'd need to instantiate it correctly:

```
std::sort(s.begin(), s.end(), ReverseComparator<char>());
```

Of course, to make it work you'd need to make the `operator()()` publically accessible. You might want to make it a `const` member function as well:

```
template <typename T>
class ReverseComparator {
public:
    bool operator()(T lhs, T rhs) const { return rhs < lhs; }
};
```

Note that the expression in the operator is changed as well: using `!(lhs < rhs)` doesn't define a strict weak order: `comparator(x, x)` would yield `true` but it is required to yield `false`.